# How to remove duplicate data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-8.0

i have table `user` like this

```
UserID   | UserName | UserEmail       | FlagUser
1        | Penny    | penny@gmail.com | A1
2        | Maika    | maika@gmail.com | A1
3        | Laila    | laila@gmail.com | A1
4        | Laura    | laura@gmail.com | A2
5        | Penny    | penny@gmail.com | A2
6        | Maika    | maika@gmail.com | A2
```

i want the result like this, if user has more than one data i want get the user with `FlagUser` A2

```
UserID   | UserName | UserEmail       | FlagUser
3        | Laila    | laila@gmail.com | A1
4        | Laura    | laura@gmail.com | A2
5        | Penny    | penny@gmail.com | A2
6        | Maika    | maika@gmail.com | A2
```

Comment: Is this the result of a `SELECT` or  a `DELETE` query?

Comment: SELECT query @GG.

Comment: which version of mysql you are using?

Comment: i'm using version 8.0.23 @KaziMohammadAliNur

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using mysql 8.0 then `row_number()` `WITH` [Common table expression](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/using-common-table-expressions/) is the convenient way:

Schema:

```
 create table user(UserID int, UserName varchar(50), UserEmail varchar(50), FlagUser varchar(50));
 insert into user values(1,        'Penny'    , 'penny@gmail.com'  ,'A1');
 insert into user values(2,        'Maika'    , 'maika@gmail.com'  ,'A1');
 insert into user values(3,        'Laila'    , 'laila@gmail.com'  ,'A1');
 insert into user values(4,        'Laura'    , 'laura@gmail.com'  ,'A2');
 insert into user values(5,        'Penny'    , 'penny@gmail.com'  ,'A2');
 insert into user values(6,        'Maika'    , 'maika@gmail.com'  ,'A2');
```

Query

```
 with cte as
 (
     select *,row_number()over(partition by username order by flaguser desc) rn
     from user
 )
 select * from cte where rn=1
```

Output:

| UserID | UserName | UserEmail | FlagUser | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Laila | laila@gmail.com | A1 | 1 |
| 4 | Laura | laura@gmail.com | A2 | 1 |
| 6 | Maika | maika@gmail.com | A2 | 1 |
| 5 | Penny | penny@gmail.com | A2 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a215ac090391e21f3ab182c4eeb02f10)*

You can also have the same result with `Inner join` and `group by` clause:

```
 select u.* from user u
 inner join
 (select username,max(flaguser) maxflaguser from user
 group by username) u2
 on u.username=u2.username and u.flaguser=u2.maxflaguser
```

Output:

| UserID | UserName | UserEmail | FlagUser |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Laila | laila@gmail.com | A1 |
| 4 | Laura | laura@gmail.com | A2 |
| 5 | Penny | penny@gmail.com | A2 |
| 6 | Maika | maika@gmail.com | A2 |

Or you can just use subquery to select single row for each user with highest value of `flaguser`:

```
 Select * from user u
 where flaguser=(select max(flaguser) from user u2 where u.username=u2.username)
```

Output:

| UserID | UserName | UserEmail | FlagUser |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Laila | laila@gmail.com | A1 |
| 4 | Laura | laura@gmail.com | A2 |
| 5 | Penny | penny@gmail.com | A2 |
| 6 | Maika | maika@gmail.com | A2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1de2cc4c4534b8d49a3c267254ea2b4b)*

Comment: thank you it worked, but can you give another way, i mean like using JOIN, i'm curious @KaziMohammadAliNur

Comment: Please let me try. Can a user have more than two rows? or more than one row with same FlagUser?

Comment: if user already has 'A2' flag, there will be no new data for that user, if user has 'A1' flag then that user will add new record with 'A2' flag

Comment: @kari I have added two more answers. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that the requirement is entirely clear, but I guess you're after something like this:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.username = x.username 
   AND y.flaguser = 'A2' 
   AND y.user_id <> x.user_id 
 WHERE y.user_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t1
FROM user t1
JOIN user t2 USING (UserName)
WHERE t1.FlagUser = 'A1'
  AND t2.FlagUser = 'A2'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only the two flags and an index on `username, flaguser`, then the fastest method might be:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.flaguser = 'A2' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from users u2
                  where u2.name = u.name and u2.flaguser = 'A2'
                 );
```